# How do I make a case where a char variable is an apostrophe?

Tags: switch-statement, quotes

So this is probably a stupid question but I'm using a switch statement as follows:

```
switch (letter) {
case 'a': return 0;
case 'b': return 1;
case 'c': return 2;
case 'd': return 3;
case 'e': return 4;
case 'f': return 5;
```

...etc

and I'm trying to use a case where letter is an apostrophe. How do i format that? Do I use double quotes: " ' " ? or single quotes: ' ' ' ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use its decimal ASCII value -
apostrophe value is 39.
So, try

```
case 39:
```

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
case '\'':
```

Using a backslash like this is called an escape sequence.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html